# c++ multiple definition errors using templates

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-definition-error

I am a new bee to template based programming and I have this error when compiling my project

```
error : multiple definition of Expr::Chapter_2<double>::get_pointer() 
objectfile.o:/Filename.h:42 first defined here.
```

The given code is entirely inside a .h header file. Any pointers to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

code :

```
template< typename T >
class Chapter_2{

-------
public :
    inline T* get_pointer();
-------
};

// Function definitions
template< typename T >
T* Chapter_2<T>::get_pointer() {
    ------code------
}

// double specialization of template
template<>
double* Chapter_2<double>::get_pointer() {
    ------code------
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't separate template classes to .h and .cpp

Comment: Did you [guard your header against multiple-inclusion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5106717/1553090)?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1)In case You have your header not starting with **#ifndef** and you have included the same header **twice** or more.

2) In a **cpp** file where you are including the header containing the template, if you have  again defined methods ( multiple definitions i.e., in cpp as well as in .h). The implementation of the methods in the template should be defined at the same place **once**.